# Subtrair soma de duas colunas

Tags: mysql, sql

Possuo uma tabela com essa estrutura:

```
...| tipo | quantidade 
      E      20
      S      15
      E      500
```

a coluna `tipo` pode ser **"E"**, de entrada, e **"S"** de saída. e a `quantidade` é um número.

Como posso efetuar um `select` que some todos os registros de tipo **"E"** e subtraia a soma de todos os registros de tipo **"S"**?

Comment: Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a que melhor por causa disto. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/101).

Comment: atualizei título e descrição

Comment: Creio que vá usar duas subqueries, com SUM e where, e depois na query maior subtrair o resultado da primeira query pela segunda e terá o TOTAL. Chegou a experimentar isto?

Comment: Sim, eu tentei isso, só que a query ficou um pouco grande, acredito que deve ter uma solução mais "elegante"

Comment: select  sum((case when tipo = "E' then 1 else -1 end) * quantidade) total from tabela

Comment: Basta somar todas as quantidades, porém quando for `tipo = 'S'` você mutiplica por -1. `SUM(IF(tipo = 'E', 1, -1) * quantidade)`

Comment: Não sei se isto tem problema de performance: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cuY4Px9VLQ1hHMjfrHTnp7/4 -- seria isto o que deseja? Ando muito enferrujado :P --- Do @Motta: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cuY4Px9VLQ1hHMjfrHTnp7/5

Comment: Agradeço, só queria uma resposta detalhada do @Motta e do Woss rs

Comment: O "CASE" retorna 1 ou -1 conforme a regra , tornando os valores positivos ou negativos , depois basta realizar um "SUM" VIDE DOCS http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-case-function/ https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum